# How does "until(-- p ---> second < 0)" loop until a non-positive value in found

Tags: c++

How does this code find a non-positive value?

```
#include <map>
#include <cstdio>

#define until(cond) while(!(cond))

using namespace std;

int main() {
  // initialization
  map<int,int> second;
  int i=10;
  int testme[10]={4,3,1,-3,7,-10,33,8,4,14};
  while (i --> 0) second[i]=testme[i];

  // find the first non-positive value in second
  map<int,int>::reverse_iterator p = --second.rend();
  do {
    printf("Is %d non-positive?\n",second[++i]);
  } until(-- p --->   second < 0);
    // "second < 0" to check if the value in second is non-positive

  printf("Yes it is!\n");
}
```

The output is:

```
Is 4 non-positive?
Is 3 non-positive?
Is 1 non-positive?
Is -3 non-positive?
Yes it is!
```

So how does the "second < 0" string check for a non-positive value?

Comment: `--p--->second<0` makes my head hurt; it should not be in production code. It's also UB. Lastly this is a variant of "here's some obfuscated code, decipher it for me please"

Comment: The *whole* code makes my head hurt …

Comment: But my favorite part about this code is how it's barely readable, and the only comments point out only the most obvious parts ("x < 0 checks if it's negative" lol)

Comment: @nos: guilty as charged; I will aim for the insanity plea after reading this code.

Comment: The fact that what is printed doesn't correspond to what is checked (p is decremented, i is incremented) is also amusing.

Comment: @AProgrammer: but `p` is a reverse iterator starting from `rend()`. So decrementing `p` is like incrementing `i`, since the map has 10 consecutive integer keys.

Comment: @AProgrammer p is a reverse_iterator ... it is just another layer of obfuscation :)

Comment: @SteveJessop, right. Is this a test entry to the IOCPPCC?

Comment: I think it's deliberately written to be difficult to read, but I suspect as a (probably-misguided) exercise.

Comment: @tenfour: btw, even if it did modify `p` twice, that would not be UB because `map<int,int>::reverse_iterator` must be a class type. So for example `(-- -- p)` is "fine", there's a sequence point between the two function calls to `operator--`, so whatever data members `operator--` modifies aren't modified twice between sequence points. Fine with the standard, I mean, not necessarily fine with me! The same code would have UB if `p` had a pointer/integer/floating type.

Comment: @tenfour: Actually this comment is also quite confusing :P

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this code to see how many people would be misled. That's why the map is named second & why the comment quotes "second < 0". @AProgrammer, it is not for IOCPPCC. I know nowhere near enough intricacies of the language to do that.

Comment: @ronalchn that's not very nice, or constructive. Mostly not appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some hints for parsing `--p--->second`. It is evaluated as `--((p--)->second)`. (Thanks to @AProgrammer for fixing my blatant error!)

- `p` is a pointer or iterator.
- `p--` decrements `p`, but returns its *previous* value as an rvalue
- `(p--)->second` accesses that value's member `second`.
- `--((p--)->second)` decrements that value (i.e. the mapped value) and returns the new, decremented value
- That new value is compared against `0`

Notes:

- The `p--` takes care of iterating over the container. Note that the loop doesn't otherwise have any explicit change of `p`.
- The outer `--` makes `0` count as a negative number. As a side effect, the loop decrements every value in the map.
- The second use of `i` is somewhat redundant. You could have written `p->second` inside the loop rather than `second[++i]`, since you already have an iterator. In fact, `second[++i]` necessitates a whole tree search.

The code is equivalent to:

```
do { /* ... */
    auto q = p;
    --p;
    --(q->second);
} until (q->second < 0);
```

Comment: I'd have though it was `--((p--)->second)`.

Comment: if it decrements twice, why does it not skip an element on each iteration???

Comment: I think AProgrammer is right, postfix and `->` bind tighter than prefix.

Comment: @KerrekSB: surely either `auto &q = *p;` or `--(q->second);`?

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, `q` is an iterator. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it check if value is not positive, and not negative: http://liveworkspace.org/code/587a9554a2b0b8f830179518133c2274

As Kerrek said

```
do { /*...*/ }
until(-- p --->   second < 0);
```

is equivalent to:

```
do { /*...*/ }
until(--((p--)->second) < 0);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
do { /*...*/ } 
while(((p--)->second)-- > 0);
```

So if value is `0` it will also break.

Comment: @AProgrammer: `!(--i < 0)` <=> `!(i-- <= 0)` <=> `i-- > 0` - I am not confusing anything. Maybe I didn't wrote too many steps at once.

Comment: while the return value of the expression is the same (true/false), the side-effect is not (it also decrements the value)

Comment: Yeah, if you want the same side effect just replace it with `while(((p--)->second)-- > 0);`. I wanted to show something - that it's not detecting just negative values and this side-effect really doesn't matter in this simple application.